# CruiseControl.rb: Error in plugin EmailNotifier: 501 5.1.7 Bad sender address syntax?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, cruisecontrol.rb

I can't seem to figure this out.  I setup my email address in cruisecontrol.rb but no matter how I set it, it always gives me this error.

Current settings are:

project/cruise_config.rb:

`project.email_notifier.emails = ['my@myemail.com']`

`project.email_notifier.from = 'noreply@myemail.com'`

site_config.rb:

`ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
   :address =>        "localhost",
   :domain =>         "myemail.com",
 }`

I've even tried

`ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :sendmail`

`Configuration.email_from = 'noreply@narble.com'`

Any thoughts as to why my cruisecontrol can't send an e-mail?  Thanks!

Justin

Answer (score 0):

Apparently all the system needed was a reboot.  Totally weird.